# Set WeeChat buffer to only notify on highlight

Tags: configuration, config, irc, weechat

I have several buffers open within [WeeChat](https://weechat.org/) of which I only read some regularly. Therefore I want to set some buffers to only change notification color in the [sidebar](https://weechat.org/scripts/source/buffers.pl.html/), if they got new messages which highlight me, but not ones that don't highlight me. The color should be the same as other buffers, where there are highlights.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into your question while looking for an answer myself. Here's the solution I found:

while in the buffer you're less interested in:

```
/buffer notify highlight
```

This sets so the buflist only highlights the buffer for highlights, not for user messages or joins/parts/etc. see `/help buffer` for more examples.

Note you can also set the default for all buffers; this setting is stored in `weechat.look.buffer_notify_default`